# Why use the module template when combining existing native project with flutter code?

Tags: ios, flutter, module

When integrating flutter into an already existing project (iOS) there are [these steps to follow](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps).

But as an alternative we can also just use:

`flutter create`

instead of:

`flutter create`**`-t module`**

and just add the classes, pods and what not from your original project in to the runner project that was create in the *ios* subfolder.

Why would creating a template module (-t module) and adding that module in the iOS project be the prefered way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [xster](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44349).

> Theoretically, `flutter create` should just be a strict superset of
>   `flutter create -t module` (with flutter create having a more fleshed
>   out iOS xcode project wrapper that you can tweak and own).
>
> But in implementation, there might be slight differences that we
>   haven't fully tested against with the rest of the add-to-app flow.
>
> We should merge them one day once the [#37910](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37910) cleanup is done.

---

> For convenience, it would do the exact same thing as it does today
>   from the surface. But behind the scene, it's shimmed out by 2 things
>   (which we can rename to make them more first class etc). A flutter
>   create -t module my_flutter_module and a flutter
>   create-wrapper-project my_test_launcher --from-module
>   ../my_flutter_module. But you can independently do just one of the 2.
>   e.g. you would call flutter create -t module to make a new Flutter
>   module. You would call flutter create-wrapper-project if you're trying
>   to create another project around an existing module etc.